# a sufficient and necessary condition for the non-negativity of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, positive-semidefinite

Find a sufficient and necessary condition for the non-negativity of
$$
f(A,B,C):=a_1 A^2 B+a_2 A^2 C+a_3 A^4+a_4 A^3+a_5 A^2+a_6 A B+a_7 A C+a_8 A+a_9 B^2+a_{10}B C+a_{11} B+a_{12}C^2+a_{13}C+1\ge0,
$$
for all $A,B,C\in\mathbb{R}$. By letting $A^2:=D$ be a new variable, it is easy to see $f$ becomes a quadratic form, say $g(A,B,C,D)$. Then there are several approaches to a sufficient and necessary condition for the non-negativity of $g$ for all $A,B,C,D\in\mathbb{R}$. However, this condition is not (?) a sufficient and necessary condition for the non-negativity of $f(A,B,C)$.
I think this problem seems to be related to the Hilbert's 17th problem. Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Another idea is to find critical point(s), and test them using second derivatives.

Comment: There are conditions that are sufficient for $g$ to be positive for *all* possible values of $D$. $A^2$ is a possible value of $D$, so they are sufficient for $f$ to be positive as well. However, necessary conditions of $g$ may not be necessary on $f$.

Comment: You can take all the discriminate of the quartic $A$, the discriminate of the quadratic $B$ and $C$, then you will get $3+2+2$ different inequalities

Comment: The discriminate of the quartic $A$ involves $B$ and $C$ and the discriminate of the quadratic $B$ ($A$) involves $A$ and $C$ ($B$ and $C$). So in doing this, it seems will lead to another problem. Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: I'm also wondering such a problem is classified as some specific problem in algebra, say positivity of real polynomials?